# Jekyll not starting

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, jekyll

I use ubuntu 19.04.

jekyll v 3.0
What am I doing wrong

```
ilya@ilya-TM1701:~/Desktop/prsng.ru$ bundle exec jekyll s 
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0/lib/jekyll/hooks.rb:54: warning: constant ::Fixnum is   deprecated
Configuration file: /home/ilya/Desktop/prsng.ru/_config.yml
        Source: /home/ilya/Desktop/prsng.ru
   Destination: /home/ilya/Desktop/prsng.ru/_site
Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
  Generating... 
     AutoPages: Disabled/Not configured in site.config.
bundler: failed to load command: jekyll (/usr/local/bin/jekyll)
NoMethodError: undefined method `validate_data!' for #<Jekyll:Page @name="index.html">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `validate_data` method was introduced in Jekyll 3.1.0
So, you'll have to update your Jekyll version.

Moreover, Jekyll 3.0.0 was released in October 2015. There has been numerous security fixes since then. Therefore, I strongly recommend updating Jekyll to at least `v3.8.6`. You can do so by running the following command:

```
gem install jekyll --version 3.8.6
```

Or simply install the latest release (`v4.0.0`) by running:

```
gem update jekyll
```